# angularjs get data from Json using $resourse

Tags: json, angularjs, get, resources

Good afternoon! Learning Angularjs. Below is the structure of the project.
I have a service that reads data from json

```
var WebKrServices = angular.module('WebKrServices', ['ngResource']);

WebKrServices.factory('DataPlant', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('plants/:plantId.json', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{plantId:'plants'}, isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

And Controller

```
var WebKrControllers = angular.module('WebKrControllers', []);

WebKrControllers.controller('PlantsCtrl', ['$scope', 'DataPlant',
  function($scope, DataPlant) {
    $scope.plants = DataPlant.query();
  }]);
```

which transmits this information to the html

```
<div ng-repeat="plant in plants">
  <h2 class="text-center">{{plant.name}}</h2>
  <a href="#/plants/{{plant.id}}"></a>
</div>
```

And, in fact question. In html I see data from json, and the controller when accessing the plants I see an empty object?

```
for (var p in plants) {
  . . .
}
```

How to get data from the plants in the controller?

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause it is asynchronous call. After   `$scope.plants = DataPlant.query();`, plants remain undefined until data arrives (Well, it is not exactly undefined, you can inspect it in debugger). When data arrives - $scope.plants get resolved and html is updated. To run some code after data arrives, use callbacks:

```
$scope.plants = DataPlant.query(function(response) {
        console.log($scope.plants);
}, function (response) {
        console.log('Error');
});
```